# process multiple items as a group

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

How can I process ("approve") multiple items in a sitecore workflow as a group? I need to get the list of items, call a webservice and then either approve or reject all of them as a group. If I create a custom workflow action it gets called once per item which does not work form me. Thanks

Comment: This answer may help you and give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13019288/661447

Answer (score 0):

You could write something do that. Get list of items that are in Submitted state and then change their state to Approve. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528431/sitecore-assign-workflow-to-an-item-programmatically).